# Android Widgets Listview Button Clicked

Tags: android, listview, widget

i have a listview in my widget that have a button in each row . 
i want to visible a view when button clicked . 
how i can found which row s button is clicked ?

```
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int i) {
  //  Log.d("MyWidgetViewsFactory", "getViewAt(" + position + "):" + items.get(position));
  //  Item item = items.get(i);

    RemoteViews itemView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_listview_item);

    if(wordItems != null) {
        itemView.setTextViewText(R.id.ques, wordItems.get(i).getWord());
        itemView.setTextViewText(R.id.answer, wordItems.get(i).getMean());

        Log.d("word item size", wordItems.size() + " -- ");


        itemView.setViewVisibility(i , View.VISIBLE);

         // -- how can find which rows is clicked and how visible a layout

        Intent intent = new Intent();

        itemView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.seeasnwer, intent);
    }
    return itemView;
}
```

Updated :

as you see in screen shot i want when i clicked "show answer" button a view set visible

[image: widget]

Answer (score 0):

Through ViewHolder concept, we can achieve it..
               or

Provide the position for button by using setTag method. Whenever click the button, get the position of that button by using getTag method and play with item what ever you want.

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: Have a glance at below URL : https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Comment: i know what is viewHolder , but cant use this in widget .

Comment: why?  whats your problem.. Even with viewHolder, it returns only view.

Comment: in android widget if i want to set text i should use this method itemView.setTextViewText(R.id.ques, wordItems.get(i).getWord());  and i cant initialized textview so viewhold it is not useful i think

Comment: if it is not feasable for your case, Provide the position for button by using setTag method. Whenever click the button, get the position of that button by using getTag method and play with item what ever you want.